# Can the directory/path on the schematics be disabled for the print in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

When you print preview from LTspice schematics the program automatically adds path/directory of the file to the bottom of the pdf.

Not really a question directly related to an electrical engineering topic but I thought someone might have information about this. I've been searching to disable it but couldn't find a way. I don't even know whether it is possible to disable this.

Basically if you are using LTspice open one of your schematic go to **File** and select **Print Preview** and look at the bottom, it will show where your file is on the pdf. Can we disable this so that we don't reveal the directory?

Comment: Must be able to because the directory doesn't appear on my own print previews. Just checked it. But it was on a schematic that I had NOT saved, yet. So that may be a clue. If you don't want the directory, just copy the entire thing onto a newly created page and print that out, I suppose.

Comment: It does not appear? Seriously? Which version are you using? XVII or IV?

Comment: Yeah. Just create a new schematic page (DraftX). Don't save it. Just create it. Open your schematic you want to print. Use the copy feature and copy EVERYTHING on that schematic into the paste buffer. Move to your draft page. Paste your schematic there. Print preview, then. I think you will see what I see.

Comment: I did right now I still see it in the unsaved new draft in mine when I check print preview.

Comment: I use version XVII

Comment: I'm using XVII(x64).

Comment: I'll gladly show you the print preview I made. No file name at all.

Comment: Maybe some other settings are different in yours. Im googling an hour

Comment: Hmm. I just got the same thing you got in making a copy. Then I just tried to open up a new schematic with NOTHING on it and tried print preview. And there was a file name. But I actually HAVE a schematic that doesn't show one, too. It is one I was actively playing with here. So I need to do some things to see if I can figure it why it doesn't show the file name. I'll let you know in a moment.

Comment: Hmm. I deleted a comment ("T") on the schematic and the file name appeared in the print preview. I restored the comment and the file name DISAPPEARED, again.

Comment: Okay. It seems that I had flummoxed the print preview. My text line was WIDE. It was "C1\* exp(t\*(-R1\*R2/L - 1/C - sqrt(C\*\*2\*R1\*\*2\*R2\*\*2 + 2\*C\*L\*R1\*R2 + L\*\*2 - 4\*L\*R1\*R2 - 4\*L\*R2\*\*2)/(C\*L))/(2\*(R1 + R2)))". That seemed to be wide enough to "kill" the filename. And it kills it in either portrait or landscape modes. So I'm guessing that while you can do it, it may not be a good solution.

Comment: Can you try to print pdf and create a pdf and then see if it will appear?  Check not the preview only but on the bottom of the real pdf.

Comment: LTspice is great, but I hope they make such things more customized soon.

Comment: The actual PDF didn't have the file name on it. So the print preview appears to be an accurate representation. I've actually had to write print preview code for Windows, so your question was a good one. However, it appears to still work. The filename is missing from the final production.

Comment: I found the trick. If you click "Zoom to full extends" and then proceed it appears. But if you right after "Zoom to full extends" left click the mouse on the schematics anywhere and move the schematics even the smallest distance it doesn't appear.

Comment: Hehe!! Great!!!

Comment: So it only appears if one preview or print right after "Zoom to full extends" Move to a bit downway.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and select it.

Comment: @pnatk, anyway to remove footer from the graph? Tried your trick and it worked on the schematics only.